# Got knit issue with R

Tags: r

[my code is working but I can not knit that part,Quitting from lines 17-19 (Homework-template.Rmd)
Error in data.frame(Davis$weight) : ÕÒ²»µ½¶ÔÏó'Davis'
Calls:  ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> data.frame
´ËÍâ: Warning message:
In has_crop_tools() :
Tool(s) not installed or not in PATH: pdfcrop, ghostcript
-> As a result, figure cropping will be disabled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rp22I.jpg)

Comment: I't un clear what you are trying to ask, what are you doing and what exactly is the issue.
Try to edit your question and explain the context + what you are doing + what error do you get. 
Good Luck.

Answer (score 13):

Agreed with [@T.G.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5836957/t-g), indeed. you need to provide a MWE for us to see what is going on. We can't help you without, as much as we'd like to - sorry.

This said, from the little we can see, you are experiencing 2 separate issues: 1 which causes your code to fail: `Error in data.frame(Davis$weight)`: some error with your data.frame as indicated in the error message and 1 which is just a warning, your markdown file should still compile just fine: `Warning message: In has_crop_tools() : Tool(s) not installed or not in PATH: pdfcrop, ghostcript -> As a result, figure cropping will be disabled.`

This warning message is how I landed on your post, looking for a solution myself... It stems from lines 315 onwards in https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/R/util.R. Here is how I "solved" this warning message under Windows, inspired by [this GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/118):

1. Run `tinytex::tlmgr_install("pdfcrop")`
2. [Install Ghostscript from this link](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html)
3. Run `Sys.setenv(R_GSCMD="C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.53.3/bin/gswin64.exe")` (adjust the version number as needed)
   If you want to check: `Sys.getenv("R_GSCMD")` or `tools::find_gs_cmd()`
   Should show what you just typed: `"C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.53.3/bin/gswin64.exe"` which is the correct path in my case.
4. `Knit` your file again - no more warning message.

Comment: For a permanent solution, i.e. for every R session: file explorer - rightclick This PC - properties - start typing Environment variables in the search box, second option, choose Environment variables - Click "Path" in System variables (lower panel) - Edit - New, type "C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.53.3\bin" or whatever your current version is: it gets appended at the end. Validate. Done.

Comment: I have been with this warning for quite a while, your solution worked perfectly for me. For the permanent solution, I needed to restarted my computer to work.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: A shortcut from above: In Control Panel: System and Security, System Properties. In advanced tab, click "environment variables". Now same as before: In System variables (lower panel) New, type "C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.53.3\bin" or whatever your current version is: it gets appended at the end. Validate. You may need to restart your computer. Done