# Rstudio pdflatex.exe did not succeed

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, miktex

I'm currently using Rstudio and R markdown to create a pdf. However, every time I attempt to knit these error messages show up:

```
! Sorry, but C:\Users\AP\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe did not succeed.

! The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

!   C:\Users\AP\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdflatex.log

Error: LaTeX failed to compile new-report.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See c2089682-report.log for more info.
In addition: Warning message:
In has_crop_tools() : 
Tool(s) not installed or not in PATH: ghostcript
-> As a result, figure cropping will be disabled.
Execution halted
```

I've attempted to uninstall/re-install MiKTex and restarting Rstudio but the problem persists. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: If you are using a Mac OS, you'll need MacTex. (Not sure on the back story, but if you're using Mac, collect MacTex via Safari, not Chrome.) If you are still looking for a solution, I suggest that you run `sessionInfo()` and add it to your question. Something as simple as an out-of-date package could be causing this. Another option could be in this question's answers may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66305776/got-knit-issue-with-r

Answer (score 14):

With a new installation of `MiKTeX`, many style files needed to knit an `RMarkdown` file to PDF are not installed. To allow MiKTeX to install them on the fly, open the MiKTeX console and go to the `Settings` tab.

There is an option that says `You can choose whether missing packages are to be installed automatically (on-the-fly)`. Make sure that this is set to **Always** to allow the necessary style files to be installed.

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: It didn't work in my laptop. I use Windows 10 and R version 4.2.0. The error says "Sorry, but C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe did not succeed.
The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
  C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\pdflatex.log
Error: LaTeX failed to compile Ensayo.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips.
Ejecución interrumpida". I did check the debugging tips but non of those work. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

For me I just went to MiKTeX console setting and choose **ALWAYS** missing packages to be installed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Go to tools on your R studio, select the global option, and click on Sweave. Under LaTex Editing and Compilation, select Use tinytex when compiling.tex file. Under PDF Preview, pick from the box RStudio Viewer. And enable Always enable Rnw concordance. Apply and Okay.

Recompile the program again! Make sure your internet is on and the computer is connected.