# Downloading a report in a Shiny app fails

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

In my Shiny app the user can build a customizable report - okay that's the purpose to achieve...

And for now the user must choose all elements (Abstract, Histogram, Additional Comments) to keep it simple. Everything in the input widgets is then transferred to the report creation (see `downloadhandler()` in app.R).

The report can be either a html or a pdf. And both variants are failing at different stages.

But now let's look at the code and for clarification: You can copy the code and run it. The only thing that has to be changed is the **html** or **pdf** in both files (app.R and report.Rmd, see comments).

**app.R**

```
# the packages I'm using (hopefully a complete list)
#library(pandoc)
#library(tinytex)
#library(bookdown)
#library(markdown)
#library(rmarkdown)
#library(knitr)
#pandoc_activate()

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        # Inputarea
        # Choose which elements should be added to the Report
        column(5,
            br(),
            checkboxGroupInput(
                inputId = "show_elements",
                label = "Choose elements to be in report",
                choices = c("Abstract","Histogram","Additional Comments"),
                selected = c("Abstract","Histogram","Additional Comments")
                #inline = FALSE,
                #width = NULL,
                #choiceNames = NULL,
                #choiceValues = NULL
            ),
            br(),
            br(),
            hr(),
            br(),
            # if Abstract is checked, then it is shown in the UI
            conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.show_elements.includes('Abstract')",
                textAreaInput(inputId="caption", label=NULL, value ="Abstract data", width = "1000px", height="100px")
            ),
            br(),
            # if Histogram is checked, then it is shown in the UI
            conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.show_elements.includes('Histogram')",
            sliderInput(inputId = "bins",
                    label = "Number of bins:",
                    min = 1,
                    max = 50,
                    value = 30)
            ),
            # if Additional Comments is checked, then it is shown in the UI
            conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.show_elements.includes('Additional Comments')",
                textAreaInput(inputId="caption_1", label=NULL, value ="further notes for the report", width = "1000px", height="100px")
            )
        ),
        # Outputarea
        column(7,
            br(),
            # if Abstract is checked, then it is shown in the UI
            conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.show_elements.includes('Abstract')",
                verbatimTextOutput("abstract")
            ),
            br(),
            # if Histogram is checked, then it is shown in the UI
            conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.show_elements.includes('Histogram')",
                plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")
            ),
            br(),
            # if Additional Comments is checked, then it is shown in the UI
            conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.show_elements.includes('Additional Comments')",
                verbatimTextOutput("add_com")
            ),
            br(),
            # The download button 
            downloadButton("reportGeneration", "Download Report")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    # Output corresponding to "Abstract"
    output$abstract <- renderText({ input$caption })

    # Output corresponding to "Histogram"
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

        x    <- faithful$waiting
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = "#007bc2", border = "white",
           xlab = "Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)",
           main = "Histogram of waiting times")

    })

    # Output corresponding to "Additional Comments"
    output$add_com <- renderText({ input$caption_1 })



    # Download the document (html or pdf)
    output$reportGeneration <- downloadHandler(
        filename = "report.html",  # if necessary change to report.pdf (app.R and report.Rmd must have either html or pdf)
        content = function(file) {
            tempReport<-file.path("C:/Users/tueftla/R","report.Rmd")
            file.copy('report.Rmd', tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
            params = list(text1=input$caption, value1=input$bins, text2=input$caption_1)
            rmarkdown::render(
                input =tempReport,
                output_file = file,
                params = params,
                envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
            )
        
        }
    )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**report.Rmd**

````
<!-- YAML header with the three parameters -->
---
title: "My R Markdown Document"
author: "tueftla"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d.%m.%Y')`"
output: html_document <!-- Depending on the app.R it could be also pdf_document -->
params:
  text1: NA
  text2: NA
  value1: NA
---

```{r include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
```
 
## Abstract <!-- Here the first parameter text1 should be used -->
 
```{r, results='asis',echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE}
print(params[["text1"]])
```
 

## Histogram <!-- Here the third parameter value1 should be used -->
 
```{r results='asis',echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE}
x <- faithful$waiting
bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = params[["value1"]] + 1)

hist(x, breaks = bins, col = "#007bc2", border = "white",
     xlab = "Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)",
     main = "Histogram of waiting times")
```

## Additional Comments <!-- Here the second parameter text2 should be used -->

```{r, results='asis',echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE}
print(params[["text2"]])
```
````

When I start the Shiny app with `runApp()` with the **html output** (in both files) the console outputs these lines:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3347
processing file: report.Rmd
output file: report.knit.md
"C:/Users/tueftla/AppData/Local/r-pandoc/r-pandoc/3.1.12.2/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS report.knit.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output pandoc50a034b324e1.html --lua-filter "C:\Users\tueftla\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:\Users\tueftla\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\latex-div.lua" --embed-resources --standalone --variable bs3=TRUE --section-divs --template "C:\Users\tueftla\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\rmarkdown\rmd\h\default.html" --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable theme=bootstrap --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url=https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" --include-in-header "C:\Users\tueftla\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp04VMVZ\rmarkdown-str50a01a17b14.html"
Output created: C:\Users\tueftla\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp04VMVZ\file50a062984a73.html
```

It seems that it works somehow, because it is saying that it's created... **but** the html file isn't there. The folder *Rtmp04VMVZ* exists and there are some files in...

**Question 1**: Where is my html file which is according to the console created?! And is it possible to just download it or even better to specify a folder where the htlm should be saved?

And now let's do the `runApp()` with the **pdf output** (in both files) and have a look at the console output:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3347
processing file: report.Rmd
output file: report.knit.md
"C:/Users/tueftla/AppData/Local/r-pandoc/r-pandoc/3.1.12.2/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS report.knit.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output pandoc50a0326f48e.tex --lua-filter "C:\Users\tueftla\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:\Users\tueftla\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\latex-div.lua" --embed-resources --standalone --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics --variable "geometry:margin=1in"
Warning in system2(..., stdout = if (use_file_stdout()) f1 else FALSE, stderr = f2)
'"pdflatex"' not found
Warning: Error in : LaTeX failed to compile C:\Users\tueftla\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp04VMVZ\file50a026d52af1.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips.
    1: runApp
```

For me it seems to fail because of a missing pdflatex?! The debugging hints changed nothing (from my perspective)...

**Question 2**: What's the issue here and how can I solve it? And like mentioned in my first question is it possible to just download the pdf or even better to specify a folder where the pdf should be saved?

Many thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT_1:** I changed the `report.Rmd` file a little. In the code chunks I'm using just the values of the `params`...

````
<!-- YAML header with the three parameters -->
    ---
    title: "My R Markdown Document"
    author: "tueftla"
    date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d.%m.%Y')`"
    output: html_document <!-- Depending on the app.R it could be also pdf_document -->
    params:
      text1: NA
      text2: NA
      value1: NA
    ---
    
    ```{r include=FALSE}
    library(knitr)
    ```
     
    ## Abstract <!-- Here the first parameter text1 should be used -->
     
    ```{r, results='asis',echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE}
    print("Abstract") #print(params[["text1"]])
    ```
     
    
    ## Histogram <!-- Here the third parameter value1 should be used -->
     
    ```{r results='asis',echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE}
    x <- faithful$waiting
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = 5 + 1) #bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = params[["value1"]] + 1)
    
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = "#007bc2", border = "white",
         xlab = "Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)",
         main = "Histogram of waiting times")
    ```
    
    ## Additional Comments <!-- Here the second parameter text2 should be used -->
    
    ```{r, results='asis',echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE}
    print("Addidtional comments"]) #print(params[["text2"]])
    ```
````

... when running `runApp()` the rendering also fails and I get these error messages

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4084

processing file: report.Rmd
                                                                                                                                                                                                     
output file: report.knit.md

"C:/Users/tueftla/AppData/Local/r-pandoc/r-pandoc/3.1.12.2/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS report.knit.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output pandoc7fcc19ef2230.tex --lua-filter "C:\Users\tueftla\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:\Users\tueftla\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\latex-div.lua" --embed-resources --standalone --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics --variable "geometry:margin=1in" 
! Sorry, but C:\Users\tueftla\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe failed.

! The log file contains hopefully all information, to make MiKTeX run again

!   C:\Users\tueftla\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdflatex.log

Warning: Error in : LaTeX failed to compile C:\Users\tueftla\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2rsGxa\file7fcc51044777.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See file7fcc51044777.log for more info.
  1: runApp
```

the log file (`C:\Users\tueftla\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdflatex.log`)

```
2024-03-11 16:51:35,134+0100 INFO  pdflatex - this process (24692) started by Rgui in directory C:\Users\tueftla\R with command line: C:\Users\tueftla\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode C:\Users\tueftla\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2rsGxa\file7fcc51044777.tex
2024-03-11 16:51:35,134+0100 INFO  pdflatex - running on Windows 10.0.19045
2024-03-11 16:51:35,139+0100 INFO  pdflatex - this is MiKTeX-PDFTEX 4.19.0 (1.40.26) (MiKTeX 24.3)
2024-03-11 16:51:35,170+0100 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2024-03-11 16:51:35,229+0100 INFO  pdflatex - going to create file: pdflatex.fmt
2024-03-11 16:51:35,229+0100 INFO  pdflatex.core - start process: miktex formats build pdflatex --engine pdftex
2024-03-11 16:51:51,269+0100 FATAL pdflatex.core - GUI framework cannot be initialized.
2024-03-11 16:51:51,269+0100 FATAL pdflatex.core - Data: 
2024-03-11 16:51:51,269+0100 FATAL pdflatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\UI\Qt\mikuiqt.cpp:126
2024-03-11 16:51:51,273+0100 FATAL pdflatex - GUI framework cannot be initialized.
2024-03-11 16:51:51,273+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2024-03-11 16:51:51,273+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\UI\Qt\mikuiqt.cpp
2024-03-11 16:51:51,273+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 126
2024-03-11 16:51:51,276+0100 INFO  pdflatex - this process (24692) finishes with exit code 1
2024-03-11 16:51:51,283+0100 WARN  pdflatex.core - still open: C:/Users/tueftla/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp2rsGxa/file7fcc51044777.tex
2024-03-11 16:51:51,283+0100 WARN  pdflatex.core - still open: file7fcc51044777.log
```

Comment: `'"pdflatex"' not found` seems like a clear error. If you're rendering this on your laptop (not deployed to a shiny server), then does `Sys.which("pdflatex")` return something other than `""`?

Comment: @r2evans Yes, I'm rendering it on my laptop and when entering `Sys.which("pdflatex")` in my console there are two lines of output: `pdflatex` (first line) and `""` (second line)

Comment: That means it is either not installed or not in the PATH that your latex chain uses. If you're using `tinytex`, I thought that it would have been installed by default, so perhaps your `tinytex` installation has gone amuck, I suggest that you look at the troubleshooting for that package and see if that helps (or perhaps just call `tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()`, though that's long/hard thing to do).

Comment: @r2evans After reinstalling `tinytex` the `commad Sys.which("pdflatex")` gives probably your expected result: `"C:\\Users\\tueftla\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\MiKTeX\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\pdflatex.exe"`. But now the report.Rmd fails in the second code chunk (lines `print(params[["text1"]])
``` `) with the error message `Warning: Error in eval: Objekt 'params' not found`

Comment: glad you got one thing figured out ... I don't see anything obvious that would cause `'params' not found` ...

Comment: @r2evans The only thing I found out through a little Google research is the topic *global variable*. Do you see here any mistake in transferring `params` from `app.R` to `report.Rmd`?

Comment: That's a great question. In my experience, I find that when I render a document and there is a `params=` in the calling environment, `render` complains and fails. Try renaming your list to something else, that is `myparms <- list(text1=input$caption, ...)` and then `render(..., params=myparms)`. (That doesn't explain the wording in that error, but perhaps it'll help a little.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257137/discussion-between-tueftla-and-r2evans).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to r2evans for supporting me in finding a solution. Extremely helpful was that he could execute the code and also retrieve the report - in HTML and PDF.

So the issue must be in my system...

Unfortunately I'm not sure about the order of the single steps but I will sum up all the single steps I made that resulted in getting the report in HTML and PDF.

1. Install MiKTeX with Single-User

   - When the question arises how missing pakages should be installed take the **ALWAYS-option** (see question [Rstudio pdflatex.exe did not succeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66305985/rstudio-pdflatex-exe-did-not-succeed))
2. Bind all the needed packages with `pacman::p_load(c("shiny", "pandoc", "tinytex", "bookdown", "markdown", "rmarkdown", "knitr"), character.only = TRUE)`
3. Activate a recent pandoc version via `pandoc_activate()`
4. Remove the comments in *report.Rmd* like r2evans said
5. And of course the output file in *app.R* und *report.Rmd* must be either **html or pdf**
6. Run the app with `runApp()` and klick the download button
7. The file (**html or pdf**) is downloaded in the folder the browser downloads them (see question and answer from Mikko Marttila [Specify destination folder for download from an R Shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71384693/specify-destination-folder-for-download-from-an-r-shiny-app))

Answer (score 1):

The use of `<!-- ... -->` as a comment works in one place only: in the *content* of a R markdown document. In your R markdown document, you have comments like that before the YAML header, inside the YAML header, and inside R code chunks, and none of those will parse or run correctly.

Adapting your code with the above changes. (No change to `app.R`.)

## report.Rmd

````
---
title: "My R Markdown Document"
author: "tueftla"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d.%m.%Y')`"
output: html_document
params:
  text1: NA
  text2: NA
  value1: NA
---

```{r include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
```
 
## Abstract <!-- Here the first parameter text1 should be used -->
 
```{r, results='asis',echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE}
print(params[["text1"]])
```
 

## Histogram <!-- Here the third parameter value1 should be used -->
 
```{r results='asis',echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE}
x <- faithful$waiting
bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = params[["value1"]] + 1)

hist(x, breaks = bins, col = "#007bc2", border = "white",
     xlab = "Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)",
     main = "Histogram of waiting times")
```

## Additional Comments <!-- Here the second parameter text2 should be used -->

```{r, results='asis',echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE}
print(params[["text2"]])
```
````

With that, I can render both HTML and, with after changing the `output_format=` and filename extension, a PDF, both without error.

[image: screenshot of the report rendered into HTML]

[image: screenshot of the same report rendered into PDF]

Comment: Thanks for your support and testing if it works on your system. This leads me to focus on my system and not on the code...