# Export Pivot table R in Markdown pdf format

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, pivot-table

I would like to get some tips about the export of pivot table to pdf file.
I have followed the method describe here http://www.pivottabler.org.uk/ but, an error message appears.
It refers to pdfcrop and ghostscript.

I have rode a lot of messages on forums (including [Got knit issue with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66305776/got-knit-issue-with-r))and tryed to re install Markdown, tinytex without results.
As I don't have administrator's right to install pdfcrop and ghostscrip, i would like to get help to get an alternative solution....
(Rstudio v1.3)
As i complexe data table,ideally I would like to continue to use the packager, it would avoid me to start all over again

Thanks

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  -\usepackage{multirow}
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r results='asis', echo=FALSE, comment=""}
pt <- PivotTable$new()
pt$addData(bhmTrains)
pt$addColumnDataGroups("TrainCategory") 
pt$addRowDataGroups("TOC",  header="Spécialité",  addTotal=FALSE)
pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="TOTAL", 
                                 summariseExpression="n()")
cat(pt$getLatex(caption="test", label="xxxxx"))
```
````

I get the following message

```
Error in pt$getLatex : objet de type 'closure' non indiçable
Calls: ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> cat
De plus : Warning message:
In has_crop_tools() :
Tool(s) not installed or not in PATH: pdfcrop, ghostscript
-> As a result, figure cropping will be disabled.
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a great time to consider the `DT` package with Rmarkdown. Here is the code with `html_document` output, this gives you the ability to PRINT the DATATABLE Directly from the document to PDF after a user makes their own pivot tables!

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---


### Chart 1
```{r echo = FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}


library(DT)
library(tidyverse)


iris %>%
  datatable(extensions = 'Buttons',
            options = list(dom = 'Blfrtip',
                           buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'),
                           lengthMenu = list(c(10,25,50,-1),
                                             c(10,25,50,"All"))))
```
````

[image]

But for PDF output, you just modify the output argument.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---


### Chart 1
```{r echo = FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}


library(DT)
library(tidyverse)


iris %>%
  datatable(extensions = 'Buttons',
            options = list(dom = 'Blfrtip',
                           buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'),
                           lengthMenu = list(c(10,25,50,-1),
                                             c(10,25,50,"All"))))
```
````

I like the DT package, because that allows you to arrange by column and save that new arrangement as it's own table, which is what a pivot table is. DT has more possibilities as well.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Daniel for your advices.
As I need to automatise tables and the reporting, I looked the features of DT to do cross tabulation, groups and sub summaries and finally I choose the GT package that appears to be the most suitable.
Thus I could easy export tables in PNG and import them in the markdown (with pdf output).